Index error trying to turn csv into dictionary lists
I am new to coding so this might be a foolish problem. I can't understand how the list index can be out range. The variable 'I' range is supposed to be the number of rows in the file and 'title' go as long as there are titles in 'headers'. But I am getting an error message: "data[title].append(row[i])
IndexError: list index out of range"
Thank you.
The csv file looks like this:
DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,SPREAD
2024-03-25 00:00,1.08071,1.08073,1.08068,1.08072,95
2024-03-25 00:01,1.08074,1.08082,1.08074,1.08079,73
2024-03-25 00:02,1.0808,1.08094,1.08078,1.08089,172
2024-03-25 00:03,1.0809,1.08094,1.08085,1.08092,167
2024-03-25 00:04,1.08093,1.08093,1.0809,1.08092,62
2024-03-25 00:05,1.08091,1.08092,1.08088,1.08091,27
2024-03-25 00:06,1.08091,1.08094,1.08088,1.08088,70
2024-03-25 00:07,1.08087,1.08096,1.08087,1.08095,25
2024-03-25 00:08,1.08096,1.08096,1.08092,1.08092,65
2024-03-25 00:09,1.08092,1.08092,1.08087,1.08089,68
2024-03-25 00:10,1.08088,1.08088,1.08079,1.08079,28

and here is my code:
import csv
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = "pathtocsv.csv"

with open(filename, "r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    headers = next(csv_reader)
   
    data = {}
    for title in headers:
        data[title] = []

    for row in csv_reader:
        for i, title in enumerate(headers):
            data[title].append(row[i])
    
for i in range(len(data["DATE"])):
    data["DATE"][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["DATE"][i],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        
for i in range(len(["OPEN"])):
    data["OPEN"][i] = float(["OPEN"][i])

for i in range(len(["CLOSE"])):
    data["CLOSE"][i] = float(["CLOSE"][i])
   

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(["DATE"], ["OPEN"])
ax.plot(["DATE"], ["CLOSE"])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.show()


Have you got a blank line at the end of your CSV file?

And as an extra hint, you have written ["DATE"] ,["OPEN"] and ["CLOSE"] in various places. You want data["DATE"] ,data["OPEN"] and data["CLOSE"] in these places instead.

Don't have enough points to add a comment, so adding as answer.
Can you check if this is applicable for your file.
From documentation
If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''

In code that will be -
with open(filename, newline='') as file:


keep length one less in  every range i.g range(len(data["DATE"])-1)
